# Redirect Main Site to Subsite in Multisite Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have multi-site wordpress, I want to redirect the main site to one of the sub-site but redirection in .htacecss gives error. Is there any way to redirect a main site to its sub-site. That looks not possible but I am not a wordpress expert so just verifying.

The redirect should be like

redirect 301 [link](http://www.example.com/main-site%20www.example.com/main-site/sub-site)

Or if there is any other way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Redirect` directive doesn't take the hostname as part of the URI path (in your case the second argument). You'll need to match that against the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main-site/sub-site
RewriteRule ^/?main-site(.*)$ /main-site/sub-site$1 [L,R=301]
```

You'll want to put these above any rules you may already have in your htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the redirection is working but after the redirection it puts index.php at the end of the URL which gives error. The index.php should not be at the end of the URL. After redirection the URL looks. www.example.com/main-site/sub-site/index.php so how I can rewrite the rule so index.php should not be in the url? It should be www.example.com/main=site/sub-site/

Comment: @Toqeer Are you putting those rules above any rules you may already have in your htaccess file? Especially ones that do index.php routing?

Comment: I am putting that in the apache configuration file. Let me try to add this in .htaccess, I put in apache because there are already rules defined.

Comment: there is are rule in .htaccess file RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /main-site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
so should I remove that and put the rules defined above?

Comment: @Toqeer I only mention htaccess because you've tagged your question with it. If this is in your server config, it shouldn't be appending a index.php unless the URL you're hitting is doing it or there's other rules that are conflicting and appending the index.php

Comment: @Toqeer don't remove anything, just add those rules *above any rules you may already have in your htaccess file* (like it says in the answer).

Comment: I added the above 4 lines at the top of the .htaccess file  and replaced with real domain and folders names but still no luck :(, still if I access www.example.com/main-site its not redirecting. I also posted the same question http://serverfault.com/questions/432105/url-redirection-in-multisite-wordpress if you can see and comment,